# Check if a set of objects is moving Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have several objects with the same tag, and I want to check if they are moving or not, to call a function when they're not moving. So I used the code bellow, but the aremoving is always false even when some objects still moving! Do you know what's wrong in my code?

**Script:**

```
bool aremoving;

void LateUpdate()
    {
        GameObject[] Cubes = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Cube");
        foreach (GameObject Cube in Cubes)
        {
            if (Cube.GetComponent<Rigidbody>() == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (Cube.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude > 0.01)
            {
                aremoving = true;
            }
            if (Cube.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude <= 0.01)
            {
                aremoving = false;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("Cubes moving: " + aremoving);
    }
```

Comment: Move `Debug.Log("Cubes moving: " + aremoving);` into the for loop to get the status for all the game objects and not just the last one.

Comment: All your cubes are better to place inside some kind of "manager" object in the hierarchy, then in a script attached to this manager you can retrieve all rigidbodies with: `GetComponentsInChildren<Rigidbody>()`, much easier than searching by tag or name in entire scene

Answer (score 1):

Write the code like this

```
bool aremoving;

void LateUpdate()
{
    GameObject[] Cubes = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Cube");
    foreach (GameObject Cube in Cubes)
    {
        if (Cube.GetComponent<Rigidbody>() == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (Cube.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude > 0.01f)
        {
            aremoving = true;
        }
    Debug.Log("Cubes moving: " + aremoving);
    aremoving  = false; 
}
```

Comment: Am still getting the same problem, aremoving=false even objects are moving

Comment: Use the float value 0.1f instead of just 0.1

Comment: Try adding `Debug.Log(Cube.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude)` What does that print?

Comment: that give some numbers like "0.0273579" and it change each frame, but sometimes it give 0 even the objects still moving

Comment: Try Using sqrMagnitude instead of magnitude.

Comment: problem still happen

Comment: How does the velocity change? Do you set it in another script? Maybe it is changing so fast that aremoving is set true and then false again? I would put extremely low number for false condition , such as 0.00001 and Debug.Log("set true") in true condition to see if this statement was ever executed.